# Cuando no paso ningun dato por la variable me sale ZeroDivisionError python

Tags: python, while

Estoy realizando un codigo simple en python en donde utilizo la funcion while para acumular datos y al final saco un promedio. El problema que me he encontrado es que si paso el codigo por un solo IF sin pasar por los demas, las variables me quedan con valor 0 y obviamente el promedio me da mal porque es algo que no se puede hacer, alguien podria indicarme si se le ocurre hacer algo en este caso:

```
conteoN=0
conteoJ=0
conteoA=0
conteoV=0
sumatoria1=0
sumatoria2=0
sumatoria3=0
sumatoria4=0
continuar=1
while continuar==1:
    peso=int(input("Ingrese peso de persona: "))
    edad=int(input("Ingrese edad de persona: "))
    if edad <=12:
        conteoN=conteoN+1
        sumatoria1=sumatoria1+peso
        print("Categoria Niños")
    elif edad <=29:
        conteoJ=conteoJ+1
        sumatoria2=sumatoria2+peso
        print("Categoria Jovenes")
    elif edad <=59:
        conteoA=conteoA+1
        sumatoria3=sumatoria3+peso
        print("Categoria Adultos")
    elif edad >60:
        conteoV=conteoV+1
        sumatoria4=sumatoria4+peso
        print("Categoria Viejos")
    continuar=int(input("Desea continuar? [1] si [0] no: "))
promedio1=float(sumatoria1/conteoN)
promedio2=float(sumatoria2/conteoJ)
promedio3=float(sumatoria3/conteoA)
promedio4=float(sumatoria4/conteoV)
print("La cantidad de niños atendidos es de :",conteoN)
print("El peso promedio de los niños es: ",promedio1)
print("La cantidad de jovenes atendidos es de :",conteoJ)
print("El peso promedio de los jovenes es: ",promedio2)
print("La cantidad de adultos atendidos es de :",conteoA)
print("El peso promedio de los adultos es: ",promedio3)
print("La cantidad de viejos atendidos es de :",conteoV)
print("El peso promedio de los viejos es: ",promedio4)
print("---FIN---")
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es cuanto intentas hacer la división para sacar el promedio con datos que tienen el valor cero. Python produce error cuando el segundo argumento de una operación de división es cero. Para solucionar el problema podrías hacer lo siguiente:

Antes de hacer la división puedes usar el operador "or" para evaluar el segundo argumento y en caso que valga cero el operador te devuelve 1. Seria algo como esto:

```py
conteoN=0
conteoJ=0
conteoA=0
conteoV=0
sumatoria1=0
sumatoria2=0
sumatoria3=0
sumatoria4=0
continuar=1
while continuar==1:
    peso=int(input("Ingrese peso de persona: "))
    edad=int(input("Ingrese edad de persona: "))
    if edad <=12:
        conteoN=conteoN+1
        sumatoria1=sumatoria1+peso
        print("Categoria Niños")
    elif edad <=29:
        conteoJ=conteoJ+1
        sumatoria2=sumatoria2+peso
        print("Categoria Jovenes")
    elif edad <=59:
        conteoA=conteoA+1
        sumatoria3=sumatoria3+peso
        print("Categoria Adultos")
    elif edad >60:
        conteoV=conteoV+1
        sumatoria4=sumatoria4+peso
        print("Categoria Viejos")
    continuar=int(input("Desea continuar? [1] si [0] no: "))
promedio1=float(sumatoria1/(conteoN or 1))
promedio2=float(sumatoria2/(conteoJ or 1))
promedio3=float(sumatoria3/(conteoA or 1))
promedio4=float(sumatoria4/(conteoV or 1))
print("La cantidad de niños atendidos es de :",conteoN)
print("El peso promedio de los niños es: ",promedio1)
print("La cantidad de jovenes atendidos es de :",conteoJ)
print("El peso promedio de los jovenes es: ",promedio2)
print("La cantidad de adultos atendidos es de :",conteoA)
print("El peso promedio de los adultos es: ",promedio3)
print("La cantidad de viejos atendidos es de :",conteoV)
print("El peso promedio de los viejos es: ",promedio4)
print("---FIN---")
```

Comment: y por que no usar un `try/except`?

Comment: @Christian. Porque no es necesario. Evaluar un simple `or` es más eficiente y limpio que los tres `try/except` que necesitarias.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, efectivamente con el OR lo pude solucionar.